# How to reset a Form when using BackboneJS and Magnific Popup

Tags: backbone.js, magnific-popup

I have a Backbone App where I use the Magnific Popup plugin for my popus. I have this issue, that when I fill out a Form and post it, then close the Popup, and then open it again, the same values I entered previously are still existing e.g the Form is not reset in any way. Is there a way to solve this?

An example of my Backbone View

```
myview.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'path/to/my/template/containing/form',
    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.appendTo("body");
        App.on('popup:form:close', this.closeformpopup);
    },
    closeformpopup(){       
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    },

    afterRender: function(){
        var servicesPopup = this.$el.magnificPopup({
            items: {
                src: '#formDiv',
                    type: 'inline',
                    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
                },
                callbacks: {
                    open: function(){
                    // ... some function
                    },
                    close: function(){
                    // reset form here!!! HOW TO DO?
                    },
                }
            }, 0).magnificPopup('open');            

}


return myview;
```

I already tried

```
$('#form')[0].reset();
```

but that didnt work, like nothing happened.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

ok, I figured it out myself by doing this:

```
close: function() {
    this.$el.remove();
}
```